# How to search the database for the username for authentication

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

can someone help me to make the "typeorm" look for a user in my "postgree" database from the username so I can validate it?

My code:

```
async findByUser(username: string) {
        return await this.userRepository.findOne({where: {username}});
}
```

I'm using NESTJS + TYPEORM + POSTGRES.

I've already done all the other settings for the validation to confirm the authentication but I'm having difficulty in this part.

Comment: You want to acess database from javascript (client browser) directly?

Comment: What isn't working with the above code?